# After build via Webpack 5 app stoped working on Internet Explorer (IE11)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webpack, webpack-5

As announced in Webpacks 5.0 release blog post build still works in most browsers after a few minor adjustments in `webpack.config.js`.

But it stopped working in Internet Explorer (11) because the generated output is mixed `ES6` and `ES5` and therefore incompatible with IE (see image).

[image: Generated Code]

As it actually leads to no successful build using a variety of babel plugins I'm asking myself if theres an "easy" way to specify ES5 as the generated output.

From beta phase of `webpack-5` I found a flag on [Medium](https://medium.com/@JayKariesch/webpack-5-beta-babel-loader-why-do-i-still-have-arrow-functions-6a22980dcae4) which seems not working anymore.

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: [name].js,
    ecmaVersion: 5 // <- this flag
  }
}
```

Is there some "webpack built in way“ in version 5.x to have ES5 as output target?

Comment: Thanks @YuZhou and @arseneyr. Both answers work but in my scenario I preferred the solution using `target:['web','es5']` as it keeps all the build relevant information on one place.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From the [webpack guide To v5 from v4](https://webpack.js.org/migrate/5/#turn-off-es2015-syntax-in-runtime-code-if-necessary), it says:

> By default, webpack's runtime code uses ES2015 syntax to build smaller bundles. If your build targets environments that don't support this syntax **(like IE11)**, you'll need to set `target: ['web', 'es5']` to revert to ES5 syntax (`'web'` if target environment is browser).

So you can try to set:

```
target: ['web', 'es5']
```

then it will convert code to ES5.

Answer (score 7):

You could manually configure the features available in the webpack runtime with [`output.environment`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputenvironment).

However, [by default](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#target) webpack 5 will honor any `browserslist` entries it finds and set the runtime to only use those features available in your target browsers. You can configure which browsers to target using any of the methods [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#browserslist), but the easiest way is to specify a key in your `package.json`:

```
"browserslist": "ie 11"
```

Comment: thanks, webpack ignored the babel IE11 configuration. I guess runtime of webpack has nothing to do with babel, it's a separate thing.