# Why isn't my Mutex class being transpiled by Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm having an issue with upgrading from Webpack 4 to Webpack 5, where Babel no longer seems to transpile code from one of my dependencies ([async-mutex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-mutex)).  I managed to strip it down to a minimal setup that demonstrates the problem:

**package.json**

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --mode=production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "~7.12.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "~7.12.0",
        "async-mutex": "~0.2.0",
        "babel-loader": "~8.2.0",
        "webpack": "~5.10.0",
        "webpack-cli": "~4.2.0"
    },
    "babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/preset-env"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": [
        "Explorer >= 11"
    ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry:  {
        bundle: './index.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                use:  'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

**index.js**

```
import {Mutex} from 'async-mutex';
console.log(Mutex);

class MyClass {}
console.log(MyClass);
```

As per my browserslist, I need to support IE 11.  After building this and inspecting the resulting `dist/bundle.js` I can see that the class `MyClass` was transpiled into a function, but the class `Mutex` was not transpiled, which obviously causes IE 11 to fail with a syntax error.  It's as if Babel is using different settings to process the `async-mutex` package than it uses to process my `index.js`.

I found [another question with an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64494479/424381) that suggests adding `target: ['web', 'es5']`, but that doesn't help and it also seems unnecessary, since Webpack is supposed to honor browserslist.

With Webpack 4 I did not have this issue, but I'm not sure if the problem is with my setup, with Webpack, with Babel or even with async-mutex.

Note aside: I'm aware that this minimal setup is lacking a Promise polyfill, but I omit it here because it seems irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: they've undoubtedly [deliberately] dropped the existing support for IE11 - but you don't need to upgrade to Webpack 5 anyway. Try to follow this wise headache free principle :: Don't fix and don't upgrade systems and apps and programs that are working flawlessly in their existing environment. Don't put a thorn on your healthy heel.

Comment: @BekimBacaj Neither Webpack nor Babel has dropped support for IE 11. And async-mutex has never directly supported it in the first place, hence the requirement for polyfills and transpilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel configuration within `package.json` only applies within your specific package, not `node_modules`, so even though Babel is set up to process all files in your bundle, it's only been configured to perform transformations on your own package's files. See the [Babel config file docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files).

You need to create a `babel.config.json` instead, or you need to put the config directly into the Webpack config, so *either*

`babel.config.json`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

OR
`webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    entry:  {
        bundle: './index.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                use:  'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    "presets": [
                        "@babel/preset-env"
                    ]
                }
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: That was it, thank you so much! (Note: The file should be named `babel.config.json` if it's in JSON format.)

Comment: Ah thanks, typed the name and forgot that I made the content JSON instead of JS.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to include `async-mutex` in your `webpack.config.js`'s module rule for babel. Once in awhile you'll come across a package that doesn't transform its ES6. Funny enough, the best way to include it in your transpilation is using `exclude`, like this:

```
module.exports = {
    entry:  {
        bundle: './index.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(async-mutex)\/).*/,
                use:  'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

This exclude rule says, "exclude all `node_modules` but `async-mutex`".

Comment: Unsurprisingly, this does not change anything. I know that it's common practice to exclude "node_modules" from babel, but I deliberately did not do that in order to include it. There is no default exclude rule as far as I know, so this does not have any effect.

Comment: Are you using `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties` in your babelrc? I see in your OP it's not there. Try adding it. You'll need to add that transform manually to transform ES6 classes.

Comment: Weird. I see the `preset-env` already has it. It seems that webpack simply isn't including that package during compilation. That much is clear. I'd try a variation of the exclude. You can find quite a few here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2031#issuecomment-244921229

Comment: Again, this makes no difference at all. Class properties seem to be a proposed addition to ES6 classes. Enabling support for this only makes sense when actually using them (which I'm not and async-mutex isn't either). `MyClass` can be transpiled just fine without it.

Comment: I understand. It doesn't matter anyway since *all* class transforms are already in `preset-env`. And on top of that, it seems `async-mutex` is targeting ES5 in its `tsconfig` build output, so it's strange to me that it's throwing that error, unless I'm reading its `tsconfig` wrong. Either way, since your class was transpiled to a function, but for some reason, according to your OP, `async-mutex` was not, it seems webpack isn't transpiling it, so I'd try various methods to include it. Also, IIRC, `target: ['web', 'es5']` only impacts webpack generated boilerplate.